# DialogFragment OnDismissListener not being called

Tags: java, android

I just did a build and noticed that my code is not working, after putting some breakpoints, I saw that, in fact, the dismiss(); method was being called, but the problem is that the Listener was not being called, so the code inside the listener never gets executed.
I have my Fragment A, where I show my DialogFragment (DateDialog), I am supossed to get some DateDialog values from my Fragment A when the DateDialog is dismissed, but it is not working.
This was my original code, it wasn´t working:

```
//DATEDIALOG
@Nullable
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.datedialog, container, false);

        localf = android.text.format.DateFormat.getMediumDateFormat(getContext());

         TomorrowB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setTomorrow();
                HasDate = true;
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

//FRAGMENT A
DateB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final DateDialog d = new DateDialog();
                d.show(getChildFragmentManagaer(), "DateDialog");
                getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
                d.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        if (d.HasDate())
                           {
                             DoStuff();
                           }
                      }

    });
```

Then, I decided to update it, using instead an interface, but it is not working either.

```
    //DATEDIALOG
     public interface DismissListener{
            void onDialogDismiss(DateDialog d);
        }

        private DismissListener mListener;

        public void setDismissListener(DismissListener listener){
            mListener = listener;
        }


        @Nullable
        @Override

        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.datedialog, container, false);

            localf = android.text.format.DateFormat.getMediumDateFormat(getContext());

             TomorrowB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    setTomorrow();
                    HasDate = true;
                    dismiss();
                }
            });

            return v;
        }


//FRAGMENT A

DateB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final DateDialog d = new DateDialog();
                d.setDismissListener(new DateDialog.DismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDialogDismiss(DateDialog d) {
if (d.HasDate())
                               {
                                 DoStuff();
                               }
                          }
```

I tried also with OnCancelListener() but its is the same.
PS:
This was indeed working until some days ago, I don't know if my migration from the Support Library to the AndroidX library has anything to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the [`onCreateDialog` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment?hl=en#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle)):

> Note: DialogFragment own the [`Dialog.setOnCancelListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnCancelListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener)) and [`Dialog.setOnDismissListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)) callbacks. **You must not set them yourself.** To find out about these events, override [`onCancel(DialogInterface)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment.html#onCancel(android.content.DialogInterface)) and [`onDismiss(DialogInterface)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment.html#onDismiss(android.content.DialogInterface)).

And this has always been the case.

You should create your own callback interface and call that from your DateDialog's `onDismiss()` rather than calling `setOnDismissListener` directly:

```
class DateDialog {
    interface DismissListener {
        void onDismiss(boolean hasDate)
    }

    private DismissListener listener = null;

    public void setDismissListener(DismissListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onDismiss(HasDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
 final DateDialog d = new DateDialog();
 d.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "DateDialog");
 getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
 d.setDismissListener(new DismissListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDismiss(boolean hasDate) {
         if (hasDate) {
             DoStuff();
         }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because of your migration to AndroidX.
The new method to register dismiss listener in AndroidX is called onDismiss() and not setOnDismissListener(). You can refer the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment.html#onDismiss(android.content.DialogInterface)). Actually Android studio should give you error at compile time for using wrong method. May be you have both libraries implemented.
So you code (from first example) should go like:

```
    d.onDismiss(new DialogInterface() {
        @Override
        public void cancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void dismiss() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: If I add that code, the dialog doesn't shows, but if I don't write it, it does, however, the main problem stills there.

Comment: `onDismiss` is the callback that `DialogFragment` calls on itself when the dialog is dismissed, it isn't how you register a listener for dismiss events.